# Using stride in metal similar to openGL

Tags: metal, metalkit

I have a buffer and the vertices have a stride. How do I specify this in metal? I cannot seem to find any example.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [MTLVertexBufferLayoutDescriptor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlvertexbufferlayoutdescriptor?language=objc), which is part of MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor. It has the `stride` member.

Below is the example of settings up three vertex attributes stored in one vertex buffer in the interleaved fashion. The `stride` is set next to the end: `vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stride = 32;`

```
MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor *pipelineDescriptor = [[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor alloc] init];

MTLVertexDescriptor *vertexDescriptor = [MTLVertexDescriptor vertexDescriptor];
vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].offset = 0;
vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].format = MTLVertexFormatFloat3; // position
vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0;
vertexDescriptor.attributes[1].offset = 12;
vertexDescriptor.attributes[1].format = MTLVertexFormatFloat3; // normal
vertexDescriptor.attributes[1].bufferIndex = 0;
vertexDescriptor.attributes[2].offset = 24;
vertexDescriptor.attributes[2].format = MTLVertexFormatFloat2; // texCoords
vertexDescriptor.attributes[2].bufferIndex = 0;

vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stepRate = 1;
vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stepFunction = MTLVertexStepFunctionPerVertex;
vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stride = 32;

pipelineDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = vertexDescriptor;
```

Comment: Thank you. What would be the approach on the shader vertex part? I basically have an array with elements of a c structure and I know that the first 8 bytes are the 2 floats I need for the vertex position. I don't need the rest of the data in the buffer. How would you approach this?

Comment: In case the extra data is never used your best option is to keep just the 8 bytes per vertex and populate the MTLBuffer with this data (use the stride of 8). In case you want to store all the data in MTLBuffer to use both by CPU and GPU (so that you avoid duplicating the positions both in the MTLBuffer and some other CPU buffer), you can specify the stride to match your data size per vertex and just ignore the extra data in the vertex function. You can omit setting respective attributes in the vertexDescriptor. Note that sharing MTLBuffer memory with CPU may be impractical for non-iOS